# Allocate object in shared memory

Tags: c++

It might be a silly question but... I have two processes P1 and P2. Can P1 allocate *easily* an object O in a shared memory that would be seen for P2? (P1 passes to P2 a pointer to O using a pipe). Something like:

```
// P1
ptr1 = new SharedMemoryObject(); // object O
pipe.send(ptr1)

// P2
ptr = pipe.recieve()
// I have access to O now
```

I want to avoid serializing and piping the objects, I would like to create them in shared memory and pass pointers

Comment: This depends heavily on the platform you use.

Comment: and to make it platform independent, you should look at the boost interprocess library, there is support for wide variety of *cool things* in there...

Comment: Docs for `Boost.Interprocess `here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/interprocess.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each process has its own address space which means that although a physical memory address may be shared between the two processes, this probably will correspond to different addresses in each process's address space. This means that when designing object that will exist in shared memory you MUST ensure they use offsets or indexes and not pure pointers.

Sharing memory will create synchronisation issues which can cause no end of problems, so unless you really have to, I will advise you to use the pipe route in preference to shared memory.

Answer (score 3):

No.  A pointer from P1 is meaningless to P2.

However, you might want to read about "based pointers", which work better for inter-process communications.

As a side-effect, any class that uses normal pointers internally (instead of based pointers) can't be shared this way.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is specifically for linux**

You can use [shm_open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open) function to create or open a shared memory file, which can be [mmap()-ed](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap). As you can see from man pages for mmap:

> The actual place where the object is
>   mapped is returned by mmap()

and

> On success, mmap() returns a pointer
>   to the mapped area. On error, the
>   value MAP_FAILED (that is, (void *)
>   -1) is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

Therefore, you can not pass the pointer from one process to another. However, you can pass the shared memory name.